# Requirejs shim doesn't load modules

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs

Here is my requirejs config:

```
paths:
  ...
  abc_routes: 'abc_routes'
  abc_model: 'abc_model'
  abc_collection: 'abc_collection'
shim: 
  ...
  'abc_routes': ['abc_model', 'abc_collection']
```

Router class:

```
define ['backbone'], (Backbone)->
    class MyApp.Routers.AbcRouter extends Backbone.Router
       index:()->
            instance = new MyApp.AbcCollection()
```

Application class :

```
require ['app','backbone', 'abc_routes'],(MyApp, Backbone, abc_routes)->
     new MyApp.Routers.AbcRouter()
```

I receive the following error at instance = new MyApp.AbcCollection():

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It looks like shim didn't preload abc_collection file.
However, when I add that file manually to require block, the app works.

Comment: Why isn't there a backbone requirement in your Router class? Also if you use `define`, the module is a normal amd module and as such shouldn't be declared as a `shim`.

Comment: yes, it is, `define backbone, (Backbone)`, what do you recommend to use instead of shim ? manually requiring files ?

Comment: Fixed, i've required my modules manually by passing them on require block.